# android - fontFamily not working on androidx

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, androidx, android-fonts

It's very strange that why fontFamily is not working on androidX .

this is my code:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="testing "
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/iransans"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

the above code doesn't effect font at all , when I convert the textview to app compact, then it works :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
```

i wanted to set my whole application font but it doesn't work as I expected :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iransans</item>
</style>
```

is there any way to solve this ? How can I use my font in entire app without setting font family for each view ?

Comment: what do you mean by not working? Is it showing an error? please specify

Comment: is the font file present in your project ?

Comment: @RohitRawat no I don't have any errors but the font is not effecting at all

Comment: @RohitRawat yes , the font exist in the font resources directory

Answer (score 41):

You are potentially running into 1+ of 3 things:

1. You're setting `android:fontFamily` but not setting `fontFamily` in your theme. make sure you have both:

```
<item name="fontFamily">@font/iransans</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iransans</item>
```

2. If you're running on older API levels, you could be running into this bug, and an upgrade to the androidx.appcompat dependency might do the trick:

   https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.1.0-alpha02
3. If you have any other themes defined in your `styles.xml`, and the parent of your `TextView` is using a separate theme, that theme may be taking precedence over the `fontFamily` attribute on the view (I have not yet determined why, but this is the scenario I'm running into myself). Setting the `android:theme` directly on my `TextView` to a style that defines the font family did the trick.

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/MyCustomFontTextAppearance" />
```

in styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyCustomFontTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/iransans</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iransans</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Number 3 was my issue! I was using android:textAppearance instead of android:theme

Comment: this should be marked as the right answer, imo

Comment: the third option solved my issue, but the question is that why setting `style` on `textview` cannot override the default `fontfamily` defined in the app `theme` and I should manually set both `theme` and `textAppearance`

Comment: + number four is inheriting from AppCompatActivity ;)
And thanks for explanation

Comment: Thanks! In my case `<item name="fontFamily">` contained an old font. I have searched for this solution for many hours.

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue, when my layout looked correctly (with custom fonts applied) in IDE preview, but without fonts on real device.

The reason of the issue was that my activity **was inherited from `Activity`, not `AppCompatActivity`**. Changing to `AppCompatActivity` resolved the issue without renaming all `TextView`s to `AppCompatTextView`s.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all fonts should be available in font dir under res dir. Example structure below:
[image]

And apply fonts whenever you want:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

On Real Device, try connecting to the internet. That solves.
[Considering you have done all necessary stuffs]

Comment: What's "all necessary stuffs"? You need to make your answer as clear as possible. Also should explain why " connecting to the internet" would solve this problem.